# Beginner in Latex: Replicating a 3D graph with vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am about to write my first document in latex and I have been struggling to find some software to draw the following picture I found in another PDF document. I learned that there is no way to extract it from a PDF and the software I found here are very complex, so I decided to learn about Tikz.

Unfortunately I succeeded only in drawing a few lines and put text and I find alignment like in this case, very difficult. Is there anyone with tips on how to draw the following?
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome, can you show us what you already got? Easier to expand existing code that start from scratch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the beginner's luck some times! But reading `pgfmanual` can't be avoided. Type `texdoc pgfmanual` from command prompt to get the manual.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={font=\footnotesize,inner sep=0pt,text=black}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0)node[mynode,anchor=west]{pet};
    \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0)node[mynode,anchor=south]{furry};
    \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2)node[mynode,anchor=north]{stroke};
    \draw[blue,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,1,0)node[mynode,anchor=south west]{dog};
    \draw[blue,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,1)node[mynode,anchor=north west]{snake};
    \draw[blue,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0.9,1.8,0.5)node[mynode,anchor=south]{cat};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for a typing exercise with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false,arrowinset=0,arrows=->](-3,-2)(3,3)
    \psline(0,2)\uput[90](0,2){furry}
    \psline(2;-150)\uput[-100](2;-150){stroke}
    \psline(2,0)\uput[0](2,0){pet}
    \psset{linecolor=blue}
    \psline(2;60)\uput[60](2;60){cat}
    \psline(2;30)\uput[30](2;30){dog}
    \psline(2;-30)\uput[-30](2;-30){snake}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't upvote above a score of 1, even if the answer in its current form does not need any improvement. A score of 1 is enough to show that the answer really works, anything above that is of no use.

Comment: I don't think that your answer works, because you don't use 3D coordinates.